# Would this trick speed up Django ForeignKey lookup?

Tags: django

I am trying to speed up my Django application. One problem I notice is that reverse lookups for foreign key relationships don't seem to be efficient.

For instance, imagine a scenario in which a teacher can have many students, but a student can only have a single teacher. One can assign a ForeignKey to a student that relates each student to a teacher. In the SQL table for student, a column called `teacher_id` tracks which teacher a student has.

When querying for which students have teacher X, all rows of the Student table must be scanned to obtain the entire query set, which seems inefficient.

What if I program Django so that every time a teacher is assigned to a student, an entry in the Teacher table, say `student_id_list` is updated; the ID of the student will be appended to a comma-separated list of other student IDs.

That way, when a query seeks all the students of a teacher, I can just use this comma-separated list of student IDs to lookup students, which is fast (ID is a primary key) and efficient (not every row of the Students table must be scanned.)

The teacher_id column in the Student table would still be used; data would just be stored twice.

Would this make my application faster? Thanks!

Comment: by any mean do not re-invent indexes! databases are optimized for the kind of scan that it's happening here. This would only make sense if you do NOT retrieve the corresponding student raws, only use the IDs as they are (which I don't think is very useful!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you want to do denormalization of your database scheme for best query performance. In this case I can recommend you application designed specially for this purpose - [django-composition](https://github.com/daevaorn/django-composition)

As documentation said:

> django-composition provides the abstract way to denormalize data from
>   your models in simple declarative way through special generic model
>   field called CompositionField.
>
> Most cases of data denormalization are pretty common so
>   django-composition has several "short-cuts" fields that handles most
>   of them.
>
> CompositionField is django model field that provides interface to data
>   denormalization.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but it's looks like wrong. Cause you'll get every student with some ID - it will be N quests to database, where N is a number of students for a teacher, while you can filter students by teacher_id, and it will be single quest for a whole number of students. 
It's can depend from indexes in DB, but it will be same "SELECT from 'students'..."

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to hack the database layer to carry extra metadata *in the database*, why not create an appropriate index in your database, or if that doesn't help, use some combination of a view or stored procedure, and use a raw sql query to invoke it?